# Как использовать autoit в языке С++

Tags: c++, autoit

Autoit невероятно удобная штука, но с С++ работать мне проще. Знаю, что Autoit написан на С. Возможно ли функционал Autoit использовать в C++? Как подключить к Visual Studio?

Comment: Насколько я помню, у них нет библиотек для включения в другие проекты. Следовательно, никак.

Comment: Поищите по ключевому слову AutoitX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для использования Autoit из C++ есть библиотека AutoItX (идет в составе [дистрибутива AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/cgi-bin/getfile.pl?autoit3/autoit-v3-setup.exe)).

Цитата из справки:

> AutoItX представляет собой DLL версию модуля AutoIt v3, которая
>   обеспечивает набор функций по AutoIt через ActiveX / COM и DLL
>   интерфейс. Это означает, что вы можете добавить AutoIt-подобные
>   функции в ваш любимый скриптовый язык, и языки программирования,
>   например, VB, VBScript, Delphi, C, C + +, KiXtart, и в большинстве
>   других языков, которые поддерживают использование библиотек (DLL).
>
> Оригинальная версия AutoIt поставлялась с двумя управляющими
>   элементами: AutoItX (COM / ActiveX Control) и AutoItDLL (управление
>   DLL). В этой новой версии как COM так и DLL версии были объединены в
>   одно управление AutoItX, который обеспечивает оба метода доступа.
>
> То как вы будете использовать AutoItX зависит от среды разработки
>   (языка) в который вы хотите его использовать. Если вы используете
>   нечто поддерживающее доступ к COM-объектам (например, VBScript), то
>   использование AutoItX в качестве управления COM весьма рекомендуется.
>   Если вы хотите использовать AutoItX из таких языков как С, то
>   использовать его в качестве DLL будет проще.

Как подключить к Visual Studio:

> 1. start a new project2. go to your Autoit directory (usually C:\Program Files\AutoIt\ )
> 2. go to the AutoItX/StandardDLL/VC6/Example folder within your Autoit directory
> 3. copy the following files to your project directory: AutoIt3.h AutoItX3.lib AutoItX3.dll main.cpp
> 4. in visual studio, go to Project->Add To Project->Files
> 5. change the "Files of type" dropdown to "all files"
> 6. Select: AutoIt3.h AutoItX3.lib and main.cpp and add them to the project
> 7. Your project should now compile and run. the example opens notepad and sends some text to it.

Также в дистрибутиве рядом с dll лежит простейший пример для C++:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "AutoItX3_DLL.h"

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // You can now call AutoIt commands, e.g. to send the keystrokes "hello"
    AU3_Sleep(1000);
    AU3_Run(L"notepad.exe", L"", 1);
    AU3_WinWaitActive(L"Untitled -", L"", 0);
    AU3_Send(L"Hello{!}", 0);

    // Get the text in the status bar
    //WCHAR szText[1000];
    //AU3_StatusbarGetText("Untitled -", "", 2, szText, 1000);
    //MessageBox(NULL, szText, "Text:", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Огромная вам благодарность. Подскажите пожалуйста ещё как избавится от такого вида строки L"notepad.exe", поскольку из за такого типа я не могу с обычным string работать.

Comment: L - префикс, который превращает строку, состоящую из char в строку, состоящую из wchar_t. Попробуйте конвертировать свою строку в этот тип данных.

Comment: Но в ожидаемых аргументах пишет тип LPCWSTR я года два назад искал информацию о преобразовании очень долго. В то время я нашол пример только для windows form

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858524/convert-char-to-lpwstr

Answer (score 2):

Когда-то давно мне понадобился язык сценариев для использования в своих приложениях. Тогда еще не было никаких Питонов и Луа, не говоря уже об Autoit. Пришлось написать свой интерпретатор языка Basic. Время шло, вышло несколько версий проекта. Сейчас этот проект называется Open Basic и он выложен в исходных кодах на:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/obasic/?source=frontpage&position=1.

Интерпретатор представляет собой класс в смысле класса С++ и написан целиком на С++, поэтому включается в любой С++ проект без всяких dll и COM-объектов. К исполняющей системе интерпретатора можно подключать пользовательские С++ функции с параметрами и вызывать их из текста Basic-программы. Там по ссылке есть и описание на русском языке.

UPD1:

> Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или
>   попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к
>   соответствующему сообщению.

Ну почему же не является? Человек спрашивает:

> Возможно ли функционал Autoit использовать в C++?

Есть куча других методов, чтобы получить функционал скриптового языка в своей программе. Кроме того, на вашем сайте в том поле которое у вас называется комментарием, невозможно вставить ссылку. Поэтому и приходится писать в том поле, которое у вас называется ответом.

UPD2:

И вообще, такое впечатление, что посетители stackoverflow занимаются не программированием, а поиском "нарушений правил" сайта stackoverflow. Поиск "нарушений правил" явно превратилось в навязчивую идею местных аборигенов. Ребята, вам с такими комплексами в ГИБДД надо работать, там ценится умение докопаться до любого столба. :-)

Comment: Кстати, отличный класс получился +. АвтоИт очень тормоз, делать что либо на нем просто, но на выходе получается нечто очень тяжёлое и неповоротливое.

Comment: @NewView Вы применили Open Basic в своем проекте?

Comment: Нет, я просто посмотрел пока :) заслуживает внимания